# Conditionally calling only some of the custom tags on a page when a form is submitted

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to make a page where a user can select a method to execute and input arguments for it.

```
<form action="thisPage.jsp" method="post">
    <h2>Select method to test:</h2> 
    <select name = 'methods' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
    <custom:inputs selectedMethod="<%=request.getParameter(\"methods\")%>" />
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="OK" />
</form>
<br /> Output:
<br />
<custom:hello arg="<%=request.getParameter(\"generatedInput\")%>" />
```

Currently I have two custom tags. The first tag, inputs, dynamically creates inputs for the user to fill, depending on the method chosen. The second tag takes the values of those inputs as an argument and displays output.

The issue is that when the form is submitted, both tags run. The tag responsible for the output shouldn't be called when the user is changing the currently selected method, or at least it should be able to know that the call was caused by method selection so it can return without executing. How can I do this, without making a separate static page for each method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resorted to AJAX, converting the tag responsible for generating the inputs into a servlet, and writing a function to request from the servlet without reloading the page:

```
var generateInputs = function() {
    $.get("inputGeneratorServlet", {
        method : $('#methods').val()
    }, function(responseText) {
        $("#inputsDiv").html(responseText);
    });
};

$(document).ready(generateInputs());
```

Instead of generating the inputs from a tag, place a `div` and update the DOM under it with the response from the call to the generatorServlet.

```
<h2>Select method to test:</h2>
<form action="thisPage.jsp" method="post">
    <h2>Select method to test:</h2>
    <select name = 'methods' onchange='generateInputs()'> 
// the select above is actually part of the things the servlet generates 
// under the div below, but I included it for clarity
    <div id="inputsDiv"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="OK" />
</form>
```

This way, changing the selected method doesn't submit the form, and the form is only submitted if the user presses the OK button, signifying that he has filled out the generated inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try [JSTL conditional tag](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

...

    <c:if test="${not empty param.generatedInput}">
        <custom:hello arg="${param.generatedInput}" />
    </c:if>
```

Thus, the output of `hello` tag will be included into page only if `generatedInput` param is not null and not empty string.

Comment: This works, but as you mentioned, only as long as the inputs are empty. If the user fills out the inputs halfway but then decides to change the selected method, the newly selected method will be run with the halfway-filled input.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Then could you add a class to all generated inputs, and on submit check if all the inputs have values, otherwise just clear populated ones? It could be achieved by [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/). If you do not use jQuery, this can be done with pure JavaScript as well.